# datasource named different than default causes NPE in DataSourcePool

Tags: playframework-2.0, datasource

I'm new to the play-framework (which I hope will simplify web-development compared to JSF/seam) and have a problem with a datasource (unfortunately the documentation is not really helpful for this problem):

I will need more than one datasource and therefore the datasource has a different name than "default".

Here is the application.conf:

```
db.monitoring.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.monitoring.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/skiline_monitoring"
db.monitoring.user=skiline
db.monitoring.password=skiline

ebean.monitoring="models.monitoring.*"
```

The model-classes for the monitoring-datasource are located in a package models.monitoring.

The model-class:

```
@Entity
public class SystemProperty extends Model {
    @Column(length=100)
    public String key;
    @Column(length=1000)
    public String value;

    public static Finder<SystemPropertyKey, SystemProperty> find() {
        return new Finder<SystemPropertyKey, SystemProperty>(SystemPropertyKey.class,      
            SystemProperty.class);
    }        
}
```

The first call to SystemProperty.find().all() produces the following exception:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:143) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:139) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
java.lang.RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourcePool.<init>(DataSourcePool.java:184) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourceManager.getDataSource(DataSourceManager.java:200) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourceGlobalManager.getDataSource(DataSourceGlobalManager.java:46) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.getDataSourceFromConfig(DefaultServerFactory.java:432) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.setDataSource(DefaultServerFactory.java:393) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:169) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
```

Adding a file ebean.properties to conf/ directory did not help. That conf/ebean.properties looks like this:

```
datasource.default=monitoring

datasource.monitoring.username=skiline
datasource.monitoring.password=skiline
datasource.monitoring.databaseUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/skiline_monitoring
datasource.monitoring.databaseDriver=org.postgresql.Driver
datasource.monitoring.minConnections=1
datasource.monitoring.maxConnections=25
datasource.monitoring.heartbeatsql=select 1
datasource.monitoring.isolationlevel=read_committed
```

Any ideas, what I am missing here (I'm using the latest stable release 2.1.2)?

Answer (score 4):

After some debugging I've found the problem:

In case the datasource has a different name than "default", you have to specify the server-name when creating a finder.

So

```
public static Finder<SystemPropertyKey, SystemProperty> find() {
    return new Finder<SystemPropertyKey, SystemProperty>(SystemPropertyKey.class,      
        SystemProperty.class);
}
```

has to be changed to

```
public static Finder<SystemPropertyKey, SystemProperty> find() {
    return new Finder<SystemPropertyKey, SystemProperty>("monitoring", 
        SystemPropertyKey.class, SystemProperty.class);
}
```